# How to combine columns in Pig FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: database, apache-pig

I have two tables:

```
1,'hello'
2,'world'
4,'this'
```

and

```
1,'john'
3,'king'
```

and I want to produce a table

```
1,'hello','john'
2,'world',''
3,''     ,king
4,'this' ,''
```

I am currently using the Pig command:

```
JOIN A BY code FULL OUTER,
     B BY code;
```

but this gives me the output:

```
1,'hello',1,'john'
2,'world',,''
,''     ,3,king
4,'this' ,,''
```

I need the code columns to combine, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes **join** will always produce output like this,its a expected behavior in pig. One option could be try **group** operator instead of **join** operator.

**a.txt**

```
1,'hello'
2,'world'
4,'this'
```

**b.txt**

```
1,'john'
3,'king'
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (code:int,name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'b.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (code:int,name:chararray);
C = GROUP A BY code,B BY code;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group,(IsEmpty(A.name) ? TOTUPLE('') : BagToTuple(A.name)) AS aname,(IsEmpty(B.name) ? TOTUPLE('') : BagToTuple(B.name)) AS bname;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,FLATTEN(aname),FLATTEN(bname);
DUMP E;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,'hello','john')
(2,'world',)
(3,,'king')
(4,'this',)
```

**BagToTuple()** is not available in native pig, you have to download the **pig-0.11.0.jar** and set it in your classpath.
**Download jar from this link:**
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpig0110jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
A = load 'a' using PigStorage(',') as (code:int,name:chararray);
B = load 'b' using PigStorage(',') as (code:int,name:chararray);
C = join A by code full outer ,B by code;
D = foreach C generate 
    (A::code IS NULL ? B::code : A::code) AS code,
    A::name as aname, B::name as bname;
dump D;
```

the result is

```
(1,'hello','john')
(2,'world',)
(3,,'king')
(4,'this,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union and then do a groupBy

Union A,B will give you:

```
1,'hello'
2,'world'
4,'this'
1,'john'
3,'king'
```

Now do a groupBy based on id. This will give you:

```
1, {'hello', 'john'}
2, {'world'}
3, {'king'}
4, {'this'}
```

Now you just need a udf to parse the bag. In udf iterate over each key to generate output in your format.

I also ran into same issue. This is how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator after your join to re-assign a new `code`, based on whether it was populated in the A or B relations.  In this example, if A.code is `null` then B.code is used, else A.code is used.

```
C = JOIN A BY code FULL OUTER, B BY code;

D = FOREACH C GENERATE
  (A.code IS NULL ? B.code : A.code) AS code,
  A.field1,
  A.field2,
  B.field3,
  B.field4;
```